# Scrapy skipping /browse/ that are not from /browse/ referer

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have a problem where my crawler is skipping browse pages that don't have a browse referrer.
What I'm trying to do it parse all pages that have a have /browse/ in the URL regardless of the referrer.

---

The following is my code(updated according to paul t):

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from wallspider.items import Website
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class anchorspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "newbrowsepages"
    allowed_domains = ["mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com/"]

    rules = (
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/browse/', ),)
    , callback="parse_links", follow= True, process_links=lambda links: [link for link in links if not link.nofollow],),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny=('/[1-9]$', '(bti=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(sort_by=)[a-zA-Z]', '(sort_by=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=32_)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=60_)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?', '(search_sort=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', 'browse-ng.do\?', '/page/', '/ip/', 'out\+value', 'fn=', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', 'search_sort=&', 'facet=' ))),
    )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return list(self.parse_links(response))

    def parse_links(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//a')
        domain = 'http://www.mydomain.com'
        for link in links:
            class_text = ''.join(link.select('./@class').extract())
            title = ''.join(link.select('./@class').extract())
            url = ''.join(link.select('./@href').extract())
            meta = {'title':title,}
            meta = {'class_text':class_text,}
            yield Request(domain+url, callback = self.parse_page, meta=meta,)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['class_text']=response.meta['class_text']
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
            yield item
```

My console log:

```
2014-01-28 12:22:03-0800 [newbrowsepages] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/ip/Ad-tech-Ultimate-Strength-Mini-8-Glue-Sticks-24-ct/17404367> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/browse/crafts/other-arts-crafts/2637_667479_1043549/?amp;ic=48_0&amp;ref=+422937&catNavId=667479&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L352)
2014-01-28 12:22:03-0800 [newbrowsepages] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/ip/Wood-Scrabble-Pendant-Tiles-Rectangle-18x20mm-100/30108666> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/browse/crafts/other-arts-crafts/2637_667479_1043549/?amp;ic=48_0&amp;ref=+422937&catNavId=667479&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L352)
2014-01-28 12:22:03-0800 [newbrowsepages] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/apparel/women/5438_133162/> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/browse/apparel/backpacks/5438_1045799_1045801_133211/?_refineresult=true&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L136)
2014-01-28 12:22:03-0800 [newbrowsepages] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.mydomain.com/ip/Advantus-Paper-Holder/24575774>
    {'canonical': [u'http://www.mydomain.com/ip/Advantus-Paper-Holder/24575774'],
     'class_text': '',
     'referer': 'http://www.mydomain.com/browse/crafts/craft-storage/2637_667479_1021741/?amp;ic=48_0&amp;ref=+420081&catNavId=667479&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L357',
     'title': [u'Advantus Paper Holder: Crafts : mydomain.com '],
     'url': 'http://www.mydomain.com/ip/Advantus-Paper-Holder/24575774'}
2014-01-28 13:45:36-0800 [newbrowsepages] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/party-occasions/plants-artificial-flowers/2637_79907/?_refineresult=true&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L355> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/)
2014-01-28 13:45:36-0800 [newbrowsepages] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/crafts/craft-storage/2637_667479_1021741/?amp;ic=48_0&amp;ref=+420081&catNavId=667479&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L357> from <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/_/N-904x?amp%3Bic=48_0&amp%3Bref=+420081&catNavId=667479&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L357>
2014-01-28 13:45:37-0800 [newbrowsepages] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.mydomain.com/browse/party-occasions/art-supplies/2637_667479_1094401/?_refineresult=true&povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L354> (referer: http://www.mydomain.com/)
```

Changed Rules to:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),), follow= True,),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/browse/', ),deny=('/[1-9]$', '(bti=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(sort_by=)[a-zA-Z]', '(sort_by=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=32_)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=60_)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?', '(search_sort=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', 'browse-ng.do\?', '/page/', '/ip/', 'out\+value', 'fn=', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', 'search_sort=&', 'facet=' )), callback="parse_links"),
```

Answer (score 2):

I see at least 3 issues here:

- your first rule references `"parse_items"` but it's not defined
- your `parse_start_url` should return the list you're building
- in `parse_page`, you should have `item = Website()` in each loop iteration, and use `yield item` at the end of each iteration

Spider code with these fixes:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from wallspider.items import Website
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class classspider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "newbrowsepages"
    allowed_domains = ["mydomain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mydomain.com/"]

    rules = (
    Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/browse/', ),)
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True, process_links=lambda links: [link for link in links if not link.nofollow],),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny=('/[1-9]$', '(bti=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(sort_by=)[a-zA-Z]', '(sort_by=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=32_)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', '(ic=60_)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?', '(search_sort=)[1-9]+(?:\.[1-9]*)?', 'browse-ng.do\?', '/page/', '/ip/', 'out\+value', 'fn=', 'customer_rating', 'special_offers', 'search_sort=&', 'facet=' ))),
    )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return list(self.parse_links(response))

    def parse_links(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//a')
        domain = 'http://www.mydomain.com'
        for link in links:
            class_text = ''.join(link.select('./@class').extract())
            title = ''.join(link.select('./@class').extract())
            url = ''.join(link.select('./@href').extract())
            meta = {'title':title,}
            meta = {'class_text':class_text,}
            yield Request(domain+url, callback = self.parse_page, meta=meta,)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//html')
        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['class_text']=response.meta['class_text']
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['title'] = site.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
            item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
            item['canonical'] = site.xpath('//head/link[@rel="canonical"]/@href').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: I still seem to be having trouble with my rules, hoping you can help.  I want to crawl all page types, but want to parse only urls with /browse/ in them

Comment: did you check that your `parse_page` callback correctly parses the pages? You can test individual callback code using this scrapy command: `scrapy parse --spider newbrowsepages --callback parse_page "http://www.mydomain.com/ip/Ad-tech-Ultimate-Strength-Mini-8-Glue-Sticks-24-ct/17404367"`

Comment: Cool, I didn't know i could check the callback, but scrapy parse --spider newbrowsepages --callback parse_links `http://www.mydomain.com/ip/Ad-tech-Ultimate-Strength-Mini-8-Glue-Sticks-24-ct/1‌​‌​7404367` the parse_link test works correctly without error, but I am running into the same problem with /browse/ pages not parsing from non /browse/ pages. I've tried playing around w/ the rules, but I cannot figure it out.  I would like to have the crawler, crawl all pages, but parse only /browse/ pages.